# How to fetch the particular column data (role column)from the migration table if the user is successfully login and return that data in laravel-8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I developed one usercontroller which contains users  and it contains one more column called  roles which will contain either Admin or user. when any registered user logins it returns token same as like i want to return the role also  (for example 6th user-id logins along with the token i want to return user role which should be fetch from the database ), please help me how to fetch that role when user successfully logins
`user migration table`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->enum('role', ['user', 'admin'])->default('user');
            $table->string('fullName');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('mobile')->unique();
            $table->string('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');

    }
}
```

`UserController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class UserController extends Controller
{
   
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'fullName'=>'required|string|between:3,15',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|regex:/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{6,}$/',
            'mobile'=>'required|digits:10',
            'role'=>'required|in:user,admin'
            ]);
        $user = new User([
            'fullName'=> $request->input('fullName'),
            'email'=> $request->input('email'),
            'password'=> bcrypt($request->input('password')),
            'mobile'=>$request->input('mobile'),
            'role'=>$request->role ,          
        ]);
        $user->save();
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Successfully Created user'],201);
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid Credentials'], 401);
            }
        }catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Could not create token'],500);
        }
        return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
        
    }
}
```

[image: This is my database from 2nd column role i want to fetch the value either admin or user]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're returning `jwt`. Decode that `jwt` token.
You can use

```
$user = json_decode(base64_decode($jwt), true);
$role = $user->role;
```

I think this should work.